# How do I train a keras model without the model.fit function using twice the memory required for the trainng data?

Tags: keras, memory, training-data

I read the training data from the h5 file with this function:

```
def get_Pierini_samples(mode: str, sample_type: str):
  config=get_config(7)
  h1_file_path=config['data']['h1']
  l1_file_path=config['data']['l1']
  if mode=="training":
    sample_z=0
    n_samples=25000
    with h5py.File(h1_file_path, 'r') as h1_file:
      with h5py.File(l1_file_path, 'r') as l1_file:
        print("Getting samples from", sample_z, "to", n_samples)
        samples=np.dstack([np.array(h1_file['noise'][sample_z:n_samples], dtype='float32'), np.array(l1_file['noise'][sample_z:n_samples], dtype='float32')])
        print("Done!")
  return samples

train_data=get_Pierini_samples(mode='training', sample_type='noise')
```

At this point I've used around 40GB of the CPU RAM.

Then I define my model:

```
def autoencoder_LSTM(X):
  inputs = Input(shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]))
  .
  .
  .

  return model

model=autoencoder_LSTM(train_data)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

But when I try to train it the RAM usage goes over 80GB and I have to reset everything.

```
model.fit(x=train_data, y=train_data, epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

I would think that since the data is already loaded, keras would just use that one.

It seems like, even though the training data is already loaded in the cpu, the model.fit() function loads it again using twice the memory. Is there a way around this?

Its worth noting that, since this is an autoencoder the samples and the labels are the same (x=y), so I should be able to save even more memory right? I've mostly programed in pytorch, I'm not used to keras yet.

Comment: You need to avoid loading the whole data and instead use generators or TF datasets which load into memory only the batch